# Issue with reading avro/json file in databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am able to read the data in Avro file but the data in the body is not showing as expected.
[image]
[image]

I have tried the above code but the body is not showing as expected.

Comment: How how do you read data...

Comment: @AlexOtt     
df=spark.read.format("avro").load("/FileStore/25__3_.avro")
df.show()

Comment: Please help me to check above screenshot

Comment: have you found a solution for this yet, i too have this issue